# How to find a character string within a string?

Tags: string, char, cstring, getline

It's only every once in awhile that I have to write in c++.  My problem is how do you find a character string within a string?  Then save that line, and then look for a set of numbers in that line.  For example I have a text file that looks like this.

Address  Length    Name
87623498  2        dog
12345678  4        cat
98737289  1        bird

I want to search for "cat" and then store the numbers associated with it (12345678) and (4) to different variable names.  Here is some code I have written, but it's not close to being correct.   I have an .exe that calls this DLL.  Any help is appreciated!
` 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
char* File_Path;  //Path is sent by another program
char* Name;   //value is being sent by another program
unsigned long Address;
int Length;
int found = 0;
{
   using namespace std;
   std::string Line;
   std::ifstream infile;
   infile.open (File_Path);
   if (infile.is_open())
   {
       std::ofstream outfile;
       outfile.open ("C:\\debug\\test.txt")
       while (infile.good()  && found == 0)
       {
           std::getline(infile,Line);
           //if (Name is within Line){
           /*I want to say IF char* Name = a part of the string line 
           ie.  Name = cat and the string Line is (12345678 4 cat)
           Then store the number (12345678 = Address), and 
           (4 = Length)  I hope that makes sense :/
            */
                outfile << Line;                 //output the stored line for debug
                outfile << address;              //output the stored address for debug
                outfile << length;               //output the stored length for debug
                found = 1;
        }
            outfile.close();
            infile.close();

     }

return 0;
}
```

` 
Please help!  Thank you!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: Homework, disguised as a "gee, I forget how to do this kind of thing, I only work in this language sometimes"?

Comment: Actually more of a power electronics engineer that, like I said, never has to write c++.  It's actually for work but I'll figure it out.  Thanks Johnny for the post, appreciate it.